# Modify python file as if it were a text file, but still having variables and such

Tags: python, text-files, editing

I am testing some python stuff, and i started wondering if it was possible to modify a python file as if it were a text file.

I have looked at the `open(<filename>, "r+")`, but this just edits the file. I can't modify it like it was a python script, modifying the actual script and not just the cache.

---

```py
#main.py

import filea

filea.var1edit("Hello world")
```

**Expected before:**

```py
#filea.py

var1 = "Text"
def var1edit(var):
  global var1
  var1 = var
```

**Expected after:**

```py
#filea.py

var1 = "Hello world"
def var1edit(var):
  global var1
  var1 = var
```

---

**Actual after:**

```py
#filea.py

var1 = "Text"
def var1edit(var):
  global var1
  var1 = var
```

Comment: Have a look at the module `ast`. That parses your Python program into an abstract syntax tree and you can then do things like change the values of literals. I suspect that your project may be more challenging than you think.

Comment: No, when running Python the files are loaded into memory. Variable names refer to in memory objects. If you assign a different object to a name you only affect the name in the running interpreter. Source files are really just an implementation detail, they don't really have to exist.

Comment: @PeterWood ok, is there antway i can edit the source file of the program then

Comment: @TheTaco you're probably trying to solve the [wrong problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). But perhaps you need a templating engine like [`jinja2`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/). If you are wanting to save state for later you could use [**`pickle`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html), [**`json`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html), or [**`csv`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) depending upon your needs. Better to search and ask questions about those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Module `ast` and `astunparse` can be useful.
We first read the `.py` file, generate the AST, modify the AST, unparse it and write the new code back. Here is an example:

```
#main.py
import ast
import astunparse

class ReWriteSource(ast.NodeTransformer):
    #visit 'Assign' node and modify
    def visit_Assign(self,node):
        if node.targets[0].id == 'var1' and isinstance(node.value,ast.Str):
            node.value.s = 'Hello World!'
        return node

#read .py file
with open('filea.py','r') as f:
    source = f.read()
#generate the AST
source_ast = ast.parse(source)
#modify the AST
ReWriteSource().visit(source_ast)
#unparse and write it back
with open('filea.py','w') as f:
    f.write(astunparse.unparse(source_ast))
```

original `filea.py`:

```
#filea.py
var1 = 'Text'
def var1edit(var):
    global var1
    var1 = var
```

modified `filea.py`:

```
#filea.py
var1 = 'Hello World!'
def var1edit(var):
    global var1
    var1 = var
```